# Mongodb sort query result by successful $in in it

Tags: python, django, mongodb, mongoengine

I've got this query.

```
db.house.find(
    { 'persons.person_id':
        { $in:
            [ ObjectId("570028671d41c8eaeb6c9ce8"), 
              ObjectId("570028681d41c8eaeb6c9e38")
            ]
        }
    })
```

At Django it looks like:

```
House.objects(persons__persons_id__in=[my_object_list])
```

And I like it.

As a result I get Houses, where 'persons.person_id' list have at least one match of ObjectId from ObjectId list (it can be more than 2 elements)

Is it possible to sort my results by successful $in's?

For example, I received 5 houses, 3 of them got 1 person_id in ObjectId list and 2 of them got 2 person_id in ObjectId list. So I want first get last these 2 houses! I apologize for the bad explanation.

Sample document from my db:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("570031aa1d41c8ed54393b19"),
    "persons" : [
        {
            "person_id" : ObjectId("570028671d41c8eaeb6c9dff"),
            "t" : "150 t"
        },
        {
            "person_id" : ObjectId("5700312d1d41c8ed54393b05"),
            "t" : "1 g"
        },
        {
            "person_id" : ObjectId("5700312d1d41c8ed54393b06"),
            "t" : "70 y"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm using Django with mongoengine, if it does matter

Comment: @JohnnyHK made it that way: `db.house.aggregate( 
 {$match: {'persons.person_id': {$in: [oid1, oid2] }}}, 
 {$unwind: "$persons.person_id"}, 
 {$match: {'persons.person_id': {$in: [oid1, oid2]}}}, 
 {$group: { _id:{"_id":"$_id"}, matches:{$sum:1}}}, 
 {$sort:{matches:-1}}
);` Unfortunately, didnt displayed anything. Any suggestions? (oid1, oid2 are my ObjectIds)

Comment: ok I just changed "persons.person_id" for "persons" at $unwind, and it did trick. Thank u